# is it possible to make a process hosted on svchost?

Tags: malware

A few days ago my little brother download a malicious file that turned out to be a Monero miner, the weird thing about it is that it runs as a windows service and hosted on svchost (the original one) when you kill it throws a BSOD, and if you try to "open file location" it says svchost in system32, and I repeat not a fake one. It closes Command Prompt, Process Hacker, and Task Manager when you open them and after I managed to open Process Hacker it showed "null" in the path field of the process I am talking about (I found it by the PID). I finally stopped by removing its schedule entry and the file associated with it, but I never found out how it was running under svchost or where the original file was. Does anyone have an idea on how this could be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to run malicious code on svchost or any other system process if you have sufficiently high privileges. Malicious code can use one of many [injection techniques](https://attack.mitre.org/wiki/Technique/T1055) to modify a running process. This has the advantage of making it harder (or nearly impossible) to detect or remove without crashing the system. In your particular case, it seems likely that your brother was infected with [WinstarNssmMiner](https://threatpost.com/new-cryptominer-distributes-xmrig-in-aggressive-attacks/132027/). Rather than making a process running *under* svchost.exe, it spawns it as a benign privileged system process and then injects malicious code into it:

> It’s unclear what the WinstarNssmMiner infection path is, but once the malware executes on a targeted system it launches a system process called svchost.exe, a process that manages system services. Next, it injects malicious code into svchost.exe.

Does the BSOD message say a critical process had died? If so, this is likely caused by the process being intentionally marked as [critical](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20180216-00/?p=98035), so its termination will bring down the system:

> The svchost.exe process created for cryptomining has a process attribute of CriticalProcess, which means terminating the process crashes the system.

This malware is new and is actively spreading in the wild. You should update your antivirus definitions. Teach your brother to only download files from official, trusted sources, or configure your system to only run [signed executables](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/security-policy-settings/system-settings-use-certificate-rules-on-windows-executables-for-software-restriction-policies). These are files that contain an embedded [digital signature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_signature) that proves that it was signed by a reputable certificate authority trusted by Microsoft.